# Selenium TimeoutException handling doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, timeoutexception

I am doing a project mentioned in the book 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'. Task is to download all images for a specific search tag from either flicks or imgur. So I chose flickr but my Timeout Exception doesn't work even if it's defined already.

```
#! python3
# download all images from Flicker using user defined Tag
import logging, os, time, requests
import pyinputplus as pyip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Ask user for a Tag
print("Hello user, this utility helps you to download images of specific 'tag' to your PC.\n")
tag = pyip.inputStr("Please choose a tag:", allowRegexes=[r'\s'])
os.makedirs(tag, exist_ok=True) # creates  folder named as user define tag

# get url
baseurl = "https://www.flickr.com/"
search_prefix= "search/?text="
search_suffix= "&media=photos"
search_url = baseurl + search_prefix + tag + search_suffix
logging.debug(f'{search_url}')

# opens firefox and get list of image links
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(2)
item_links = []
for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('overlay'):
    item_links.append(item.get_attribute('href'))

print('Python script has found %s images.\n' % (len(item_links)))
count = pyip.inputInt('How many images would you like to download?') 

# getting all links for images
image_links = []
for i in range(0,count):        
    image_link = str(item_links[i]) + 'sizes/l/'
    logging.debug(f'{image_link}')
    driver.get(image_link)
    try:
        webelement = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#allsizes-photo > img:nth-child(1)')))
        image_links.append(webelement.get_attribute('src'))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        pass

# downloading all images   
for link in image_links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    response.raise_for_status()
    file = open(os.path.join(tag,os.path.basename(link)), 'wb')
    for chunk in response.iter_content(100000):
        file.write(chunk)
    file.close()

print('Done.')
```

Everything is working fine until webelement is not located due to download restrictions even though "except TimeoutExceptions' is defined. I found out that the css_selector changes from #allsizes-photo > img:nth-child(**1**) (if present) to #allsizes-photo > img:nth-child(**2**) (if not) but I have an impression that the exception should be able to handle that. Could you please advise what am I doing wrong?

Link examples as requested:

**webelement present** [flickr.com/photos/bjarnekosmeijer/48718018992/sizes/l](http://%20webelement%20present%20flickr.com/photos/bjarnekosmeijer/48718018992/sizes/l%20timeoutexception%20flickr.com/photos/ebanatawka/5062862631/sizes/l)

**timeoutexception** [flickr.com/photos/ebanatawka/5062862631/sizes/l](http://%20webelement%20present%20flickr.com/photos/bjarnekosmeijer/48718018992/sizes/l%20timeoutexception%20flickr.com/photos/ebanatawka/5062862631/sizes/l)

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iivDR.png)

[webelement present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q51yU.png)

Comment: Can we have url ?

Comment: webelement present https://www.flickr.com/photos/bjarnekosmeijer/48718018992/sizes/l/

timeoutexception https://www.flickr.com/photos/ebanatawka/5062862631/sizes/l/

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this `CSS`

```
div#allsizes-photo img
```

with `visibility_of_element_located` in **explicit wait**

**Code :**

```
driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/photos/bjarnekosmeijer/48718018992/sizes/l/")
webelement = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#allsizes-photo img")))
print(webelement.get_attribute('src'))
```

**Output**

```
https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48718018992_7cbf09802a_b.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but would you be also able to tell what have I done wrong with the TimeoutException?

Comment: it did thank you